# Оптимальная выборка из бд

Tags: php, yii2, rest

Делаю выборку по городу, у города есть районы, у них комплексы, а у комплексов квартиры.В конечном итоге мне нужно получить квартиры для определенного города, с указанием сопутствующих фильтров(район,комплекс и т.д).
На данный момент сделал так:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $cities = Cities::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->request->get('city_id')])->with([
        'districts' => function ($query){
            $query->filterWhere([
                'id' => Yii::$app->request->get('district_id'),
            ]);
        },
        'districts.complexes' => function ($query) {
            $query->filterWhere([
                'id' => Yii::$app->request->get('complex_id'),
                'type_id' => Yii::$app->request->get('complex_type_id'),
                'developer_id' => Yii::$app->request->get('developer_id'),
            ]);
        },
        'districts.complexes.apartments' => function ($query) {
            $query->filterWhere([
                'amount_room' => Yii::$app->request->get('amount_room'),
                'yardage' => Yii::$app->request->get('yardage'),
                'level' => Yii::$app->request->get('level'),
                'price' => Yii::$app->request->get('price'),
            ]);
        },
    ])->all();
    $query = [];
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        foreach ($city->districts as $district) {
            foreach ($district->complexes as $complex) {
                foreach ($complex->apartments as $apartment) {
                    $query[] = $apartment;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $query,
    ]);
}
```

Но выглядит как-то костыльно, возможно я пошел не тем путем, и можно сделать оптимальнее?

Comment: добрый день. пошли совсем не тем путем. Надо в моделях сделать связи таблиц через hasMany или hasOne и потом просто вызвать модель района и остальное все само подтянется и получится один большой массив. Делать 4 foreach совсем не круто.

Comment: @SOFQ3, Так связи есть, и по ним то как раз вызываю, но у одного города много районов, а у каждого из этих районов много комплексов, и у них много квартир. 4 foreach самого смущают, поэтому и задал вопрос сюда. Как конкретно можно избавится от переборки foreach?

Comment: так какой должен быть конечный итог? зачем получать все эти апартаменты?

Comment: Получить нужно квартиры(апартаменты) во всем городе.

Comment: а если попробовать выбирать не города как сейчас, а квартиры и сделать связку до города и потом сгруппировать по городу то получим все квартиры в городе.

Comment: Так я вот и задал вопрос о том как это сделать не в теории а в практике:)

Comment: давай структуру БД, сделаем че-нить. В теории у тебя уже все написано только надо перевернуть всё в обратном порядке. типа `Apartment::->find()->join('complex')->join('district')->join('city')->groupBy('city.id')->all()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63174/discussion-between-edvardpotter-and-sofq3).

Comment: Сделал почти так как вы предложили, большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел такое решение:

```
public function actionIndex()
{        
    $query = Apartment::find()
        ->joinWith('complex')
        ->joinWith('complex.district')
        ->joinWith('complex.district.city')
        ->where(['cities.id' => Yii::$app->request->get('city_id')])
        ->filterWhere(['districts.id' => Yii::$app->request->get('district_id')])
        ->filterWhere(['complex.id' => Yii::$app->request->get('complex_id')])
        ->filterWhere(['complex.type_id' => Yii::$app->request->get('complex_type_id')])
        ->filterWhere(['complex.developer_id' => Yii::$app->request->get('developer_id')])
        ->filterWhere(['apartment.amount_room' => Yii::$app->request->get('amount_room')])
        ->filterWhere(['apartment.yardage' => Yii::$app->request->get('yardage')])
        ->filterWhere(['apartment.level' => Yii::$app->request->get('level')])
        ->filterWhere(['apartment.price' => Yii::$app->request->get('price')]);

    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
}
```